# SIM5360E GPS/GSM Module UART communication

Tags: module, gps, embedded, at-command, gnat-gps

While I'm connecting the SIM5360E module with USB to uart converter and am sending at+commands through putty, I am getting some null values as shown below.
Please help me to rectify the issue:

> AT+CGPS=1,1
>   AT+CGPSINFO
>   result
>   +CGPSINFO:,,,,,,,,
>
> OK

Comment: You need to include the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying with below code 
And i suppose to get the location details in between the commas as shown in result 
am getting only commas as result

```
AT+CGPS=1,1
AT+CGPSINFO
```

- result 
  CGPS,,,,,,